# C# throws error when interpreting embedded document value of empty array []

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, null, embedded-documents

Here is the information about my development environment:

MongoDB 3.0.0

MongoDB C# Driver Version 1.7.0.4714

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

.NET Framework 4.0

Here is a C# Class whose objects will be used as embedded documents:

```
   public class Location
   {
       public double lng { get; set; }
       public double lat { get; set; }
   }
```

Here is a C# Class used to represent a person's house:

```
   public class House
   {
       public String houseDescription { get; set; }
       public Location locOfHouse  { get; set; }
   }
```

We have a C# API module used by mobile application component that will set the
locOfHouse = []

which means that in the MongoDB Collection called House, we could have the following document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56c455ee26b49c090019b439"),
  "houseDescription" : "Multi-floor house with elevator and staircase",   
  "locOfHouse" : []
}
```

In my C# application, I have the following class mappting to BSON

```
     if (false == BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(House)))
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<House>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.MapProperty<Location>(c => (Location)c.locOfHouse);

            });

        }
```

However, the web-based C# application throws the following error when retrieving the aforementioned data:

```
An error occurred while deserializing the locOfHouse property of class 
House: Expected a nested document representing the serialized form of a Location 
value, but found a value of type Array instead.
```

How do I change my C# application code in such a way the it will Not throw the aforementioned error?

Comment: *Why* is the "C# API module" setting `locOfHouse` to an empty array? That's the broken code - I would initially try to fix that rather than making everything else work around the broken data.

Comment: It is handled by a different developer, and he wants me to just handle the empty array in my code.

Comment: You should agree on a data model. If the model is that `locOfHouse` is meant to be a single value, the other developer should change their code. If the model is that `locOfHouse` should be a collection (which seems very odd to me), you should change your `House` class. Trying to maintain two incompatible data models is a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 1):

Change with List

```
public Location locOfHouse  { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Location> locOfHouse  { get; set; }
```